# Plot line after line with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I want to plot something *row after row*, because each row `c[row]` has not the same length. Here is the code that I use. Each row is mapped/rendered to the interval [0,1], regardless if c[row] had 2,4, or 100 elements.

```
 #vmin = ...
 #vmax = ...
 gca().set_autoscale_on(False)
 for row in range(len(c)):
   imshow([c[row]], interpolation = 'nearest', vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax, extent = [0, 1, row*1.0/len(c), (row+1.0)/len(c)])
```

It works, but the aspect ratio is always square! I cannot add `aspect=` something else because as `imshow` is called each time for a line only!

How can I get a rectangle ratio (example 2:1 instead of square 1:1)

(Or maybe there is a better idea to plot *line after line* rather than `imshow`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the aspect ratio of the `axes`

```
ax = gca()
ax.set_aspect(2)
plt.draw()
```